# Многопоточная обработка файлов с использованием ExecutorService

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как сделать чтобы один поток подсчитывал количество строк в одном файле, второй во втором и т.д.?

```
public class ThreadMain {
    static ArrayList<File> FilesFind = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mask;
        Scanner DIR_NAME = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner MASK_NAME = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Введите директорию :");
        getFilesList(DIR_NAME.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Введите маску для поиска");
        mask = MASK_NAME.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Результат поиска :");

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new ThreadPools(FilesFind, mask);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Потоки закончили работу");
    }

    public static void getFilesList(String nameDirectory) {
        File f = new File(nameDirectory);
        for (File str : f.listFiles()) {
            if (str.isFile()) {
                FilesFind.add(str);
            } else if (str.isDirectory()) {
                getFilesList(str.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `ThreadPools`:

```
class ThreadPools implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<File> FilesFindThread;
    private String maskThread;
    private String search;


    ThreadPools(ArrayList<File> FilesFind, String mask) {
        this.FilesFindThread = FilesFind;
        this.maskThread = mask;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        CountStrings();
    }

    public void CountStrings() {
        for (File fill : FilesFindThread) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fill));
                int count = 0;
                while ((search = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (search.contains(maskThread) && !search.isEmpty()) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ":" + "Name files :" + fill.getName() + " ---- > " + count);
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Статический метод [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29) предназначен для создания пула с фиксированным числом потоков (это число вы указываете в качестве параметра конструктора). Если количество задач будет больше числа доступных потоков, то они добавляются в очередь и извлекаются из нее по мере освобождения одного из потоков.

С помощью метода `execute()` мы запускаем выполнение определенной задачи (выполнение может начаться сразу или позже, см. выше).

Поскольку нам необходимо многопоточно обработать определенное число файлов, то просто добавляем их обработку в качестве очередной задачи, за все остальное уже отвечает `ExecutorService`.

Для завершения выполнения пула потоков используем два метода:

- [`shutdown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) - сообщаем, что наш сервис больше не принимает никаких новых задач.
- [`awaitTermination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) - блокирующий метод пока все задачи не будут выполнены, либо текущий поток не будет прерван, либо не будет достигнут указанный таймаут.

Далее привожу пример многопоточного чтения файлов и подсчет количества строк в них. Пояснил код комментариями. Пример легко сможете адаптировать под свою задачу, добавив более сложную логику по поиску файлов на основе фильтров.

Основной метод для получения исходного каталога и запуска обработки файлов:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    // Считываем исходный каталог для поиска файлов.
    System.out.print("Введите исходную директорию для поиска файлов:");
    final String directoryPath = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();

    File directory = new File(directoryPath);
    // Убедимся, что директория найдена и это реально директория, а не файл.
    if (directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory()) {
        processDirectory(directory);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Не удалось найти директорию по указанному пути.");
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Метод `processDirectory(File directory)` для поиска файлов и их обработки:

```
private static void processDirectory(File directory) {
    // Получаем список доступных файлов в указанной директории.
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if (files == null) {
        System.out.println("Нет доступных файлов для обработки.");
        return;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Количество файлов для обработки: " + files.length);
    }

    // Непосредственно многопоточная обработка файлов.
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for (final File f : files) {
        if (!f.isFile()) {
            continue;
        }

        service.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                    int lines = 0;
                    while (reader.readLine() != null) {
                        ++lines;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Поток: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". Файл: " + f.getName() + ". Количество строк: " + lines);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // Новые задачи более не принимаем, выполняем только оставшиеся.
    service.shutdown();
    // Ждем завершения выполнения потоков не более 10 минут.
    try {
        service.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Пример выполнения данного кода:

```
Введите исходную директорию для поиска файлов: C:\projects\FindCentroid\src\pro\parshinpn
Количество файлов для обработки: 6
Поток: pool-1-thread-1. Файл: Cluster.java. Количество строк: 25
Поток: pool-1-thread-4. Файл: Point.java. Количество строк: 90
Поток: pool-1-thread-3. Файл: Graph.java. Количество строк: 120
Поток: pool-1-thread-2. Файл: Edge.java. Количество строк: 92
Поток: pool-1-thread-6. Файл: Vertex.java. Количество строк: 69
Поток: pool-1-thread-5. Файл: UnionFindStructure.java. Количество строк: 102
```